# Failed attempt to plot a parallel line through a known point using axline and/or solving for y=mx+b

Tags: python, math

I am trying to use plt.axline, within python, to draw a line parallel to another line running through two points. I know the coordinates of an adjacent point that I would like the parallel line to run through.

I cant make plt.axline work at all using the slope call. i.e. plt.axline((x0, y0),slope=m)

So, two things:

1. It would make life easier if I could just used axline with a slope call
2. why is it when I solve for y=mx+b my parallel line fails?

Thanks in advance!

My failed code is below:

```
x0 = 2457460.6130471006;y0 = 552976.7722723632
x1 = 2455541.591031033 ; y1 = 553865.0073953888
x2 = 2456838.6408896423; y2 = 550689.8369019731

%matplotlib notebook
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5))

plt.scatter(x1,y1,color="red",marker="x",s=100,label="p1 = x1,y1")
plt.scatter(x2,y2,color="blue",marker="x",s=100,label="p2 = x2,y2")
plt.axline((x1, y1), (x2, y2), linestyle='--', color='black', zorder=0) 

plt.scatter(x0,y0,color="green",marker="x",s=100,label="p0 = x0,y0")

m = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1) # slope of the line p1 -> p2
print('m = Slope of line through p1 and p2 = '+str(m))
b = y0/(m * x0) # y=mx+b -> b=y/mx
print('\nb = y intercept = '+str(b))

xnew = x0+10000  # picks some x point off in the distance
ynew = m*xnew+b # solves for the y at the x point off in the distance

# Draws a line with same slope running through p0
# plt.axline((x0, y0),(xnew, ynew), linestyle='--', color='red', zorder=0) 
plt.axline((x0, y0),slope=m, linestyle='--', color='red', zorder=0) 

plt.legend()
```

Here, it works, when not attempting to use axline:

```
x0 = 2457460.6130471006;y0 = 552976.7722723632
x1 = 2455541.591031033 ; y1 = 553865.0073953888
x2 = 2456838.6408896423; y2 = 550689.8369019731

%matplotlib notebook
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5))

plt.scatter(x1,y1,color="red",marker="x",s=100,label="p1 = x1,y1")
plt.scatter(x2,y2,color="blue",marker="x",s=100,label="p2 = x2,y2")
plt.axline((x1, y1), (x2, y2), linestyle='--', color='black', zorder=0) 

plt.scatter(x0,y0,color="green",marker="x",s=100,label="p0 = x0,y0")

m = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1) # slope of the line p1 -> p2
print('m = Slope of line through p1 and p2 = '+str(m))
b = y0/(m * x0) # y=mx+b -> b=y/mx
print('\nb = y intercept = '+str(b))

xnew = x0+10000  # picks some x point off in the distance
ynew = m*xnew+b # solves for the y at the x point off in the distance

# Draws a line with same slope running through p0
# plt.axline((x0, y0),(xnew, ynew), linestyle='--', color='red', zorder=0) 
# plt.axline((x0, y0),slope=m, linestyle='--', color='red', zorder=0) 

plt.legend()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it has to be `b = y0 - m*x0`, as

```
y = mx + b    |-mx
b = y - mx
```

Comment: I must have been tired yesterday... Thanks!